# Merging namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

How can I merge the same namespaces that are scattered over different files in to one file?
I am using Resharper but it doesn't seem to have this option.

Order is not important.

Something like: `copy *.cs output.cs` but this doesn't merge namespaces.

Comment: I don't think there is a predefined method of doing this. Could you not iteratively check the files (find by text) for similar namespace declarations?

Comment: Why would you? Multible classes in one file is not exactly 'come il faut' :-)

Comment: @Flater I have about 50 `.cs` files that use exact same namespace and I need to join them.

Comment: i would say copy paste. The reason resharper does not do this is because it does not know the order of the lines and can essentially break your program. you need to read the code and determine where it must be before you move it.

Comment: If there is no need for a particular order, i would take 5 or ten minutes to make a small console app that opens each cs file and gets the content within each class or namespace, and then save it into one .cs file

Comment: What is the advantage of this? Why do you want everything chucked into a single code file? That just makes maintenance more difficult.

Comment: @Jonny No there is no need for any kind of order. I just want everything under one namespace. No scattering. It would be nice to see your solution as an answer, though. :)

Comment: lol, give me ten or so minutes.

Comment: The correct way to order code in namespaces are: folders for namespaces, files for classes. Why put all classes from one namespace in one file?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I can't see any good reason placing all your code in one file in one namespace.

Comment: @vandango: it gets a bit more complicated than that when you work with multiple inter-dependent projects :p

Comment: @Jonny As long as there is only one namespace grouped per file the ordering of types within the file doesn't matter .. R# doesn't offer the option simply because it's not a "common/expected/supported task".

Comment: @TomasJansson When you have over 500 files or more with the same namespaces scattered all over trust me its not a nice thing to see. Confusing as hell. Especially if you want to port this code to other language.

Comment: @user3060326 Now, R# *does* have the ability to organize Classes into Files and Namespaces into Folders, which makes file-based navigation much simpler. There is no "inverse". If the Namespace/Type explorer that directory structure (and file names) are irrelevant anyway. As such, it is generally much more practical to have 500 classes in 500 files (in X directories) than to have 500 classes in 1 file .. SCMs usually like it better too.

Comment: @Kilazur: sure, but that's the base idea :)

Comment: That is entirely true.

Comment: I can agree with that doesn't sound like a nice scenarion, but copying everything to the same file isn't the solution I would go for. Maybe copy the files in the same namespace to the same folder and then go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to join the namespaces. I did not put in a duplicate line checker because you may have different classes that may cointain identical lines. Though, LIke all the comments, i dont think its a good idea to have so many classes in one namespace. Its like haveing 500 woman in one house. None the less, Just change the file extension to .cs and your IDE will tell you the duplicate names and remove them. It should take about 2 minutes if you do find and edit all that meet search criteria.

here is the codeL

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    StreamReader reader;
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(/*where you want the final txt to be saved. rename the extension to .cs  */);

        string line;
        int count = 0;
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(/*where your cs files are*/");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            // do something with fileName

            File.Copy( fileName, /* location to save the now txt .cs files */ + count.ToString() + ".txt");
            count += 1;
        }
        string[] Completetxt = Directory.GetFiles(/*location where you saved the txt files */);

        foreach (string TxtFile in Completetxt)
        {
            reader = new StreamReader(TxtFile);
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Just remember this copies all the cs files into one file with all the imports below each other as well as namespace names. Just use your IDE to find the copies and delete them.

Best of luck